# How can I copy and rename the same file with a list of names?

Tags: nautilus, 13.10, files, batch

I wish to copy an image (`grey.png`) and rename the copies with using [this long list of names](http://pastebin.com/DnJNxx6n)

Is there any way? (running 13.10)

Answer (score 2):

I'll presume that you have the list of names in a file at `/path/to/target_names`.

To make the copies, open an terminal and `cd` to the directory containing this file. Then run

```
for i in $( </path/to/target_names tr -d ',' ); do cp grey.png ${i}; done
```

Instead of copying, which will multiply the size required by the number of new files, you could use using symlinks instead, where each new file references the original file, without copying it.

```
for i in $( </path/to/target_names tr -d ',' ); do ln -s grey.png ${i}; done
```

N.B. that if you use symlinks, you won't be able to change the relative paths of the original and the targets later. i.e. they will have to stay in the same directory. (You can make the symlink for an alternative directory with the original command if you like.)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have file `names.txt` with all this images names.

Create a new folder for copies:

```
mkdir copies
```

Now do a little test. This should output all filenames

```
for name in `sed -r 's/,/\n/g;s/ *//g' names.txt`; do echo $name; done
```

If this works fine do next step.

Finally do a copies to `copies` folder. I suppose you execute this in a folder where `names.txt` and folder `copies` are located.

```
for name in `sed -r 's/,/\n/g;s/ *//g' names.txt`; do cp grey.png copies/$name; done
```

Comment: Great answer, but perhaps you should add `cd copies` after the `mkdir`.